# Regex conditionally remove text within parens

Tags: python, regex

I was wondering how to remove the following text from a string in python using regular expressions.

```
string = "Hello (John)"
(magic regex)
string = "Hello "
```

However, I only want to remove the text in the parens if it contains the substring "John". So for example,

```
string = "Hello (Sally)"
(magic regex)
string = "Hello (Sally)"
```

Is this possible? Thanks!

Comment: What about `Hello (sir john lol)` ? Also have you tried anything ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be the gist of what you want:

```
>>> from re import sub
>>> mystr = "Hello (John)"
>>> sub("(?s)\(.*?John.*?\)", "", mystr)
'Hello '
>>> mystr = "Hello (Sally)"
>>> sub("(?s)\(.*?John.*?\)", "", mystr)
'Hello (Sally)'
>>> mystr = "Hello (John) My John (Sally)"
>>> sub("(?s)\(.*?John.*?\)", "", mystr)
'Hello  My John (Sally)'
>>>
```

Breakdown:

```
(?s)   # Dot-all flag to have . match newline characters
\(     # Opening parenthesis
.*?    # Zero or more characters matching non-greedily
John   # Target
.*?    # Zero or more characters matching non-greedily
\)     # Closing parenthesis
```

Comment: You have to change the dots to exclude parentheses as they are too greedy. `re.sub("(?s)\(.*John.*\)", "", "Hello (John) My John (Sally)")` results in `Hello `.

Comment: Right, I see.  Fixed.

Comment: Quick correction: DOTALL mode allows the dot to match **newlines**; the rest of the whitespace characters are always matched.

Answer (score 1):

If you to just remove all instances of John, you can do:

```
string = "Hello (John)"
string.replace("(John)", "")
print(string) # Prints "Hello "
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
REGEX = re.compile(r'\(([^)]+)\)')

def replace(match):
    if 'John' in match.groups()[0]:
        return ''
    return '(' + match.groups()[0] + ')'

my_string = 'Hello (John)'
print REGEX.sub(replace, my_string)
my_string = 'Hello (test John string)'
print REGEX.sub(replace, my_string)
my_string = 'Hello (Sally)'
print REGEX.sub(replace, my_string)

Hello 
Hello 
Hello (Sally)
```